# How to append a third column in a dataframe using conditions from 2 other columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have the following data frame,

```
uuid    variable    value
AAS Highly_Active   False
AAS Highly_Active   True
SAP Highly_Active   False
SAP Multiple_days   True
YAS Highly_Active   False
YAS Highly_Active   False
YAS Busi_weekday    False
```

And I need to use the values from the column `variable` and `value` to define third column `Activity` and I have following classic python code doing it but my primary data frame is 121Mb in size and so its taking long time. Any pandas solutions would be great

```
def activity(row):
    if row['variable'] == "Highly_Active" and row['value'] ==True:
        val = "Highly_Active"    
    else:
        val = "NO"
    if row['variable'] == "Multiple_days" and row['value']==True:
        val = "Multiple_days"    
    else:
        val = "NO" 
    if row['variable'] == "Busi_weekday" and row['value']==True:
        val = "Busi_weekday"
    else:
        val="NO"
    return val
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['Active']=(df.variable*df.value).replace('','No')
df
Out[653]: 
  uuid       variable  value         Active
0  AAS  Highly_Active  False             No
1  AAS  Highly_Active   True  Highly_Active
2  SAP  Highly_Active  False             No
3  SAP  Multiple_days   True  Multiple_days
4  YAS  Highly_Active  False             No
5  YAS  Highly_Active  False             No
6  YAS   Busi_weekday  False             No
```

Comment: @user1017373 yw~ :-)

Comment: If OP needs just 3 statuses (but has more), then this wouldn't work.. hmm... maybe you could pre filter somehow.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Let us waiting for OP to clarify this :-)

Comment: @user1017373 aha :-)

Answer (score 3):

KIS, `np.where` -

```
status = ["Highly_Active", "Multiple_days", "Busi_weekday"]

df['Activity'] = np.where(
  df['variable'].isin(status) & df['value'], 
  df['variable'], 
  'NO'
)
```

```
df

  uuid       variable  value       Activity
0  AAS  Highly_Active  False             NO
1  AAS  Highly_Active   True  Highly_Active
2  SAP  Highly_Active  False             NO
3  SAP  Multiple_days   True  Multiple_days
4  YAS  Highly_Active  False             NO
5  YAS  Highly_Active  False             NO
6  YAS   Busi_weekday  False             NO
```

---

If @Paul H is right and `isin` is redundant in the solution above, then you can just use `pd.Series.where`/`pd.Series.mask` -

```
df['variable'].where(df['value'], 'NO')
```

Or,

```
df['variable'].mask(~df['value'], 'NO')
```

```
df

  uuid       variable  value       Activity
0  AAS  Highly_Active  False             NO
1  AAS  Highly_Active   True  Highly_Active
2  SAP  Highly_Active  False             NO
3  SAP  Multiple_days   True  Multiple_days
4  YAS  Highly_Active  False             NO
5  YAS  Highly_Active  False             NO
6  YAS   Busi_weekday  False             NO
```

Comment: my guess is that you don't actually need `df['variable'].isin(status)` but it's hard to know that.

Comment: @PaulH Oh wow, in that case it becomes as simple as `df['variable'].where(df['value'], 'NO')`

Comment: @user1017373 See edit... are you interested in all statuses? Or just a few? Wen's solution will not work for the second case.